# Python: how to go from the bytes produced by a camera to an actual image

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, byte

I am controlling a microscope camera through its SDK, and end up with image data in what I suppose is byte format. Here is how the SDK display the camera image using Qt:

```
image = QImage(img_buf, img_width, img_height, (img_width * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4, QImage.Format_RGB888)
```

Since I'm not really interested in displaying the camera stream in a Qt environment but rather in saving videos made by this camera, I am wondering what the process to go from the 'byte format image' to the actual image/movie? I have been recommended to look into PIL, but I can't find good examples on how to use it. Most examples first transform an actual image into bytes, and then process it back into an image of different compression, but how to build images from raw byte data like in my situation?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we refer to "actual image", there are few choices.
`QImage` object may be considered as "actual image".
Using PIL, we are going to get PIL Image object instead of QImage.

I prefer to see "actual image" as NumPy array.
An RGB image in NumPy representation is:
`img_height` rows, `img_width` columns and `3` color channels.
(The shape of the array is `img_height` x `img_width` x 3).

---

We may represent the RGB image as follows:

```
      <-- img_width r,g,b triples -->
   r00,g00,b00, r01,g01,b01, r02,g02,b02, ...   ^
   r10,g10,b10, r11,g11,b11, r12,g12,b12, ...   | img_height rows 
   r20,g20,b20, r21,g21,b21, r22,g22,b22, ...   |
   r30,g30,b30, r31,g31,b31, r32,g32,b32, ...   V
```

The same RGB image in bytes array (`img_buf`) may be represented as long 1D array.
(When reshaping to an image, line scan is from left to right and from top to bottom):

```
r00,g00,b00, r01,g01,b01, r02,g02,b02, ..., r10,g10,b10, r11,g11,b11, r12,g12,b12, ..., r20,g20,b20, r21,g21,b21, r22,g22,b22, ..., r30,g30,b30, r31,g31,b31, r32,g32,b32, ...
```

---

Lets assume `img_width` is a multiple of 4 (ignore: `(img_width * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4`).
The conversion from `img_buf` to RGB NumPy array is done is two steps:

- Convert `img_buf` from bytes array to NumPy array:

  ```
   buf_as_np_array = np.frombuffer(img_buf, np.uint8)
  ```
- Reshape the NumPy array to `img_width` columns, `img_height` rows and 3 color channels:

  ```
   rgb = buf_as_np_array.reshape(img_height, img_width, 3)
  ```

In one statement: `rgb = np.frombuffer(img_buf, np.uint8).reshape(img_height, img_width, 3)`

---

We may convert `rgb` to PIL image object:

```
im = PIL.Image.fromarray(rgb)
```

---

I prefer to use OpenCV package, because it uses NumPy arrays natively.
The only issue is that OpenCV color ordering convention is BGR and not RGB.
We may convert RGB to BGR:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

Example for writing `img` to PNG file using OpenCV:

```
cv2.imwrite('img.png', bgr)
```

---

When the `img_width` is not a multiple of 4, we may use `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided`:

```
img_stride = (img_width * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4

buf_as_np_array = np.frombuffer(img_buf, np.uint8)  # Convert the bytes array to NumPy array
rgb = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(buf_as_np_array, (img_height, img_width, 3), (img_stride, 3, 1))  # Use "stride_tricks.as_strided" because img_width*3 != bytesPerLine
```

I hope it is not the case, because it's difficult to explain the concept of "strides"...

---

For demonstration I created two code samples.

Image width is a multiple of 4:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_width = 128
img_height = 80

# Create sample bytes array for demonstration:
################################################################################
cols, rows = img_width, img_height
sample_img = np.full((rows, cols, 3), 60, np.uint8)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'R', (cols//2-60, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'G', (cols//2-20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'B', (cols//2+20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
img_buf = sample_img.tobytes()  # Convert the image to bytes array
################################################################################

buf_as_np_array = np.frombuffer(img_buf, np.uint8)  # Convert the bytes array to NumPy array
rgb = buf_as_np_array.reshape(img_height, img_width, 3)  # Reshape the 1D array to img_width columns by img_height rows and 3 color channels.

# Convert from RGB to BGR, and show image (for testing).
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # Converting from RGB to BGR (only because OpenCV convension is BGR)
cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Image width may not be a multiple of 4:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img_width = 130  # Width is not a multiple of 4 (bytesPerLine is going to be 392 instead of 390=130*3 due to padding)
img_height = 80
img_stride = (img_width * 24 + 31) // 32 * 4  # 392 In QImage the name is "bytesPerLine"

# Create sample bytes array for demonstration:
################################################################################
cols, rows = img_width, img_height
sample_img = np.full((rows, cols, 3), 60, np.uint8)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'R', (cols//2-60, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (255, 0, 0), 3)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'G', (cols//2-20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 255, 0), 3)
cv2.putText(sample_img, 'B', (cols//2+20, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, 2, (0, 0, 255), 3)
sample_img = sample_img.reshape(img_height, img_width*3)  # Reshape from 130x80x3 to 390x80
sample_img = np.pad(sample_img, ((0, 0), (0, img_stride-img_width*3)), mode='constant')  # Pad 2 columns to 392x80
img_buf = sample_img.tobytes()  # Convert the image to bytes array
################################################################################

buf_as_np_array = np.frombuffer(img_buf, np.uint8)  # Convert the bytes array to NumPy array
rgb = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(buf_as_np_array, (img_height, img_width, 3), (img_stride, 3, 1))  # Use "stride_tricks.as_strided" because img_width*3 != bytesPerLine

# Convert from RGB to BGR, and show image (for testing).
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(rgb, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR) # Converting from RGB to BGR (only because OpenCV conversion is BGR)
cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Sample output:
[image]

Comment: Nice explanation!